# how to loop over array of objects to filter out based on another array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have an array of objects and an array of string. I need to remove certain elements from the array of string based on the value in the objects.

And this needs to happen in the render method in react.

```js
this.state.pillarNames.forEach(pillarName => 
     (pillarData.find(pillar => 
       pillar.name === pillarName) === undefined ?
         <MenuItem
           style={{ fontSize: '14px'
           value={pillarName}
           key={pillarName}
           name={pillarName}
         ></MenuItem> : null
     )
   )
```

I have tried something like this and is not working.

```js
pillarNames = ["abc", "xyz", "def", "hij"];
pillarData = [{
  name: "abc",
  value: 1
}, {
  name: "xyz",
  value: 2
}];
```

So, I need only "def" and "hij" from pillarNames. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter and then with the result array [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
const pillarNames = ["abc", "xyz", "def", "hij"]
const pillarData = [{name: "abc", value: 1}, {name: "xyz", value: 2}]

// ...

pillarNames.filter(pn => pillarData.find(pd => pd.name === pn)).forEach(pn => /* your logic... */)
```

Comment: @ShripradaS Glad to help